# Loging to google account through powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm trying to build a powershell script to post a file from fileshare to Google drive using Invoke-WebRequest and Google script, I already got a script which works when the Google script is public unfortunately I need to have it locked to domain of company I'm working for.

My idea is to login to my Google account and then direct the session to the Google script but I'm stuck on login form is this even possible or it will never work ? I know there are easier ways with oauth tokens but everything is locked down by security policies from IT and we don't have access to GCP

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Powershell script that You Can use for the automatic logon to Gmail under Internet Explorer:
[image]